# Failed do_rootfs for agl-demo-platform

Tags: yocto

I am building Yocto for AGL image (for more details: automotivelinux.org).

The below error occurred during the build progress (do_rootfs).

In packagegroup-agl-demo-platform.bb, declared packagegroup-agl-image-ivi as a runtime dependent package.

```
RDEPENDS_${PN} += "\
    packagegroup-agl-image-ivi \
    "
```

I can build successfully the packagegroup-agl-image-ivi separately. But when building the whole agl-demo-platform image, happened as follows:

```
ERROR: agl-demo-platform-1.0-r0 do_rootfs: Unable to install packages. Command '/LTSI4.9/LTSI4.4/build/tmp/work/m3ulcb-agl-linux/agl-demo-platform/1.0-r0/opkg.conf -t /LTSI4.9/build/tmp/work/m3ulcb-agl-linux/agl-demo-platform/1.0-r0/temp/ipktemp/ -o /LTSI4.9/build/tmp/work/m3ulcb-agl-linux/agl-demo-platform/1.0-r0/rootfs  --force_postinstall --prefer-arch-to-version   install 
run-postinsts
screen 
kernel-modules
packagegroup-agl-devel
packagegroup-core-eclipse-debug
mc packagegroup-core-tools-profile 
kernel-module-vsp2 kernel-module-pvrsrvkm
kernel-module-vspm-if
opkg packagegroup-core-tools-debug
psplash kernel-module-vspm
packagegroup-core-ssh-openssh
packagegroup-agl-demo-platform
omx-user-module kernel-devicetree'
returned 1:

Solver encountered 1 problem(s):
Problem 1/1:
  - package packagegroup-agl-demo-platform-1.0-r0.all requires packagegroup-agl-image-ivi, but none of the providers can be installed

Solution 1:
  - do not ask to install a package providing packagegroup-agl-demo-platform


ERROR: agl-demo-platform-1.0-r0 do_rootfs: Function failed: do_rootfs
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /LTSI4.9/build/tmp/work/m3ulcb-agl-linux/agl-demo-platform/1.0-r0/temp/log.do_rootfs.14498
ERROR: Task (/LTSI4.9/meta-agl-demo/recipes-platform/images/agl-demo-platform.bb:do_rootfs) failed with exit code '1'
```

Can anyone help me out in this case ?

Comment: I did a first practice to remove RDEPENDS of packagegroup-agl-image-ivi. It can bypass the error. But it's only workaround. For further development, I need this agl-image-ivi (as recommended: http://docs.automotivelinux.org/master/docs/devguides/en/dev/reference/meta-agl-demo.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried 02 ways as follows. They did work.

First method, I cleaned all relative packages and rebuild the whole image.

```
$ bitbake -c cleanall -c cleansstate <recipes>
```

**recipes** consisted of all dependent & runtime dependent packages. But it was a little bit confused to inexperienced users to determine which ones.

Second method, I wiped out the **build/tmp/**, **cache/**, **sstate-cache/** folders, and re-build all Yocto packages. 
There were nothing happening any more. It was really a bad idea if be in critical period of time, but if have free time, be helpful.